# AngularJS - UI-Routing - how to use the route state as variable in controller?

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, angularjs-scope, angular-ui-router

I am using Angular JS and UI-Routing. The routing works fine. My problem is showing and hiding a slider depending on what page the user is on.

My index.html looks something like this:

```
<body ng-app="myApp">

<header ng-include="'templates/header.html'"></header>
<div>Code for slider</div>


<!--=== Content Part ===-->
<div class="container"> 
<div class="row" >
    <div ui-view autoscroll="false"></div>
</div>


</div><!--/container-->     
<!-- End Content Part -->

<footer ng-include="'templates/footer.html'"></footer>
```

my app.js looks like this:

```
angular
.module('myApp', ['ui.router'])
.config(['$urlRouterProvider','$stateProvider',function($urlRouterProvider,$stateProvider){
    $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/');
    $stateProvider
        .state('home',{
            url: '/',
            templateUrl: 'templates/home.html'
        })
        .state('about',{
            url: '/about',
            templateUrl: 'templates/about.html'
        })
        .state('contact',{
            url: '/contact',
            template: 'CONTACT'
        })
}])
.controller()
```

Now I tried to include the slider in the home.html template but then it does not properly work due to initialisation requirements. When I use a controller in the different routes it is out of scope. So how do I pass a variable referring to the state to a controller indepent of the route so I can use it for it something like

```
if (state==home) {
   $scope.showSlider==true;
}else{ $scope.showSlider==false;}
```

Thanks,

Gerd

UPDATE:
@Chris T

I have added this to my app.js:

```
 .controller('myController',['$scope', '$state', function($scope,$state){
if ($state.includes('home')){
    $scope.showIt=true;

}else{
    $scope.showIt=false;
}
 }])
```

Then I applied the controller to a div I wrapped around the slider and used

```
 ng-show="showIt"
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Inject $state into your controller. Then check if `$state.includes("home");`

Update:
I made a plunk with a parent state which controls the slider enabled/disabled based on $state.includes('main.home')

http://plnkr.co/edit/eT1MW0IU53qfca6sGzOl?p=preview

Comment: Thanks Chris, I got it to work but only in the .config of the ui-routing... which then has a controller and a scope outside of the slider part in the HTML... I get an error when I try to create a new controller and pass in $state outside of the ui-router config. Any suggestions of what might be wrong or how I pass my result to another controller?

Comment: Can you show me how you are creating the controller and injecting $state?

Comment: I have added the controller as an update to the original question.Thanks for your help!

Comment: I understand the question better now.  You have a couple of options.  Your slider is operating outside of a controller context.  You could embed the logic directly in the markup, using $rootScope to access $state (meh): http://plnkr.co/edit/SkiBwv3uxghsT4UYUQ9j?p=preview  or you could create a parent state (better) with a controller.

Comment: Hey Chris, thanks for the very detailed answer. The enabling/disabling of the slider according to the state does work now however allthoug the slider shows up it does not work properly. It is a parallax slider and only the background image appears, also the music of the youtube video which should be loaded on top as a second layer but it does not show nor does the text. I have noted this to be true for everything that gets injected that the global files the seemed to be the loaded like the .js files for the slider or .css files for content do not affect the injected elements. Any solution?

Comment: .js and .css added directly to the main page (index.html) is added to the global scope (window) and should be available for use within ui-router views.  Does your slider and youtube control require javascript to be run in order to initialize them?  If so, you may need to put the initialization code in an appropriate place.  You might want to wrap the init code in a directive, for instance.

Comment: You really are the man. I have added the init code for starting the slider to a template file and integrated the slider via ng-include. The code is much cleaner now.